# Highcharts Legend item text alignment

Tags: highcharts, legend, jscript, legend-properties

I have the following problem:
I would like to align the text of the legend in the following way:
Legend:

[Color1] Title1:---------------100.000.000€

[Color2] Title23343334:-----100.000.000€

[Color3] Title23343334:------10.000.000€

Do you know how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need to set `useHTML`: true, and define html elements in the `labelFormatter` function, and set the widths of those elements via CSS.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yra1rw51/

(there are numerous ways to set up the HTML and CSS to accomplish this - this is just one example)

Comment: thank you for your help. But how can I adjust the CSS so that the Icon of the legend-item and the title of legend-item has no space between each other, as in the standard version? In your example I have some space, I think because of the display: inblock-property. If I delete it, the numbers are not aligned right, as in your example.

Comment: The spacing is a matter of the margin and padding settings. Simply remove those: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yra1rw51/10/

Answer (score 0):

You can define [itemWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.itemWidth) which define static with of each legend item.

Comment: I saw that this is useful when the legend layout is horizontal. I use the vertical layout, so that the legend items are one below the other.

Comment: Let me know where the problem is when you have it vertical, because then itemWidth also can be applied.

Comment: Sebastion - the problem isn't the item width. The user wants a fixed width for the first part of the legend text, and then the data value for that entry aligned to the right of it.